# JTable sort by date

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have a **JTable** with two columns, **fileName** and **date modified**. I have added name **String** for the first column and added `new Date(tempFile.lastModified())` for the second dateTime column.

I rendered the dateTime column as a `new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")` String.

I also enabled the  `m_listTbl.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);`

But the sort result in the **date modified** column is not right.

[image]

Why is this? Do I still need to write my own sorter?

**EDIT:**

After commented out almost all extra code and not rendered by date String, I got the following result. It seems in JTable Java sort **Date** object by **day** by default. I will test more to see what's wrong with my code.
[image]

**EDIT2**

I have tested and figured out. If you use DefaultTableModel without overriding its getColumnClass() method, you will have trouble with Date or Number columns.

Comment: Because there is a problem in your code. Show us the relevant code.

Comment: Are you saying by default, JTable will be able to sort Date correctly? then I will look at my code more carefully.

Comment: Why don't you just define how they are comparable yourself this will have many more uses down the road then learning how to use some arbitrary table sorting method.

Comment: @TylerHeiks: there is no need to tell how they are comparable, since Date implements Comparable already.

Comment: @JBNizet Date absolutely does but at which point did he say he was using date class for the column itself; looked to me like they were both Strings. (yes, I know he is using date in the program)

Comment: That's why I asked for the code. Without seeing the code, we can only guess.

Comment: Consider  table.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(model))

Comment: @DwB - no, no need to: that's exactly what the table does internally (with the autoCreateRowSorter property to true, as the OP did)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2 : Absolutely. Having the same problem in a jtable linked to a `tablemodel` I can confirm that the problem is due to the class associated to the column value (EDIT2) in the `tableModel`. Surprise was that Date column was of class Object no matter a perfect type Date was returned in my subclass of `DefaultTableModel` when overriding public Object `getValueAt(int row, int col)`.

Workaround is to override `getColumnClass` in your subclass of `DefaultTableModel`. If you don't do that, sorting is done on Object for Dates with strange results when you sort the Date column.